# rails 4 belongs_to relation and associations results in NoMethodError

Tags: model, ruby-on-rails-4, foreign-keys, belongs-to

i'm trying to work out my `belongs_to` relations in rails 4: i have three tables - a `hardware` table, an `entity` table and a `replacement` table. `entities` is a view:

```
db=> \d entities;
      View "public.entities"
   Column    |  Type   | Modifiers
-------------+---------+-----------
 id          | integer |
 device      | text    |
 entity_type | text    |
 serial      | text    |
```

and i create the other two with migrations:

```
class CreateHardwares < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :hardwares do |t|
      t.string :vendor
      t.string :model
      t.decimal :price
    end
  end
end

class CreateReplacements < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :replacements do |t|
      t.belongs_to :entity
      t.belongs_to :hardware
      t.integer :quantity
      t.belongs_to :replacement_hardware
    end
  end
end
```

so the basic idea is that a `replacement` refers to an entity (like a pc). it also holds information of it's (current) `hardware` and the replacement `hardware` for the entity.

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
      self.primary_key = "id"
  has_one :replacement
end

class Hardware < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Replacement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entity
  belongs_to :hardware
  belongs_to :replacement_hardware, class_name: "Hardware", :foreign_key => 'replacement_hardware_id'
end
```

so i populate the tables with some stuff and try a query:

```
Replacement.includes(:entity).where(:id=>1)
  Replacement Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "replacements".* FROM "replacements"  WHERE "replacements"."id" = 1
  Entity Load (2.4ms)  SELECT "entities".* FROM "entities"  WHERE "entities"."id" IN (35692)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Replacement id: 1, entity_id: 35692, entity_type: nil, hardware_id: nil, quantity: nil, replacement_hardware_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>
```

ok, looking good.. however, when i try to access the association `entity`, it throws an error:

```
Replacement.includes(:entity).where(:id=>1).entity
NoMethodError:   Replacement Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "replacements".* FROM "replacements"  WHERE "replacements"."id" = 1
  Entity Load (3.8ms)  SELECT "entities".* FROM "entities"  WHERE "entities"."id" IN (35692)
undefined method `entity' for #<Replacement::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fb156f6e758>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read more about associations. If you define a belongs_to relationship you should also add the corresponding ids to your migration.

For example, if a Replacement belongs to an Entity you should have entity_id in your replacements table. Otherwise replacement has no knowledge about its associations. Once you have done that you can actually call the relationships.

Some additional notes: You don't have to define id as a primary key in entity. Stick with the conventions and only define primary keys if they differ from the default. Your Entity model also doesn't have any relationships defined. A relationship goes both ways and should be defined as such.

Comment: from the postgres output, i do have `entity_id` in my `replacements` table (bit difficult to put the output in these comments). also, doesn't the `belongs_to` migration statement create that for me?

Comment: Not if you define relationships afterwards. Anyway, updated my answer to provide additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Duh! just to answer my own question so i can search for it again (in case i'm stupid enough to repeat my mistakes)... it basically boils down to the `where` statement. as `where` returns an array of objects, it of course does not know what `entity` is. so sticking it in a loop or doing `first` will work as expected! ie

```
Replacement.includes(:entity).where(:id=>1).first.entity
```

or

```
Replacement.includes(:entity).where(:id=>1) do |r|
    r.entity
end
```